# Callable function available globally on Vue app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this function that tied down to a css animation plugin called `animatecss`

```
function animateCss(element, animationName, callback) {
  const node = document.querySelector(element)
  node.classList.add('animated', animationName)

  function handleAnimationEnd() {
      node.classList.remove('animated', animationName)
      node.removeEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd)

      if (typeof callback === 'function') callback()
  }

  node.addEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd);
}
```

is there a way I can make it a valid Vue callable function that is available entirely to my Vue app, I use to call it e.g.

```
animateCss('#el', 'fadeInDown', function(){
    console.log('animation completed');
});
```

I can make it `window.animateCss` to declare it as a global variable but seems not neat to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set

```js
Vue.prototype.$animateCss = function(element, animationName, callback) {
  const node = document.querySelector(element)
  node.classList.add('animated', animationName)

  function handleAnimationEnd() {
      node.classList.remove('animated', animationName)
      node.removeEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd)

      if (typeof callback === 'function') callback()
  }

  node.addEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd);
}
```

before creating your App, you'll be able to use `this.$animateCss` in all of your components.

You might also want to read up on [(Global) Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin) that provide this functionality in a more flexible way.

Comment: where should I put this, before new Vue({}); or after it?

Comment: before `new Vue()`, but after importing/loading `Vue` itself into the page

Comment: this "Vue.prototype.$animateCss = animateCs" not working but if I do this "Vue.prototype.$animateCss = function()" now its working.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my mistake when copy-pasting!

Comment: "Vue.prototype.$animateCss = function(.." seems not available entirely to components, im using Vue CLI

Comment: I just ran a new `vue create` and I was able to use `this.$animateCss` in the main `App.vue` as well as the `HelloWorld.vue` component, calling it in `mounted()`. So there must be a mistake on your end.

Comment: I'm calling it from the nested component of a component via created and not mounted

Comment: When you're calling it in `created()`, the elements are not added to the DOM yet, so the function cannot add the class names to them. If you really want to set it in `created()`, you could wrap it in `this.$nextTick(() => { this.$animateCss('img', 'myanimation'); });`, but why not just do it the proper way?